# Running MySQL via Batch File - Rogue Character

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having a few issues trying to run the following MySQL from a Windows batch file.

I have created a batch file called `restore_database.bat` that contains list line:

```
C:\wamp\mysql\bin\mysql --user=root --password=abc123456 mydatabase < C:\Temp\mydatabase.sql
```

Now when I run restore_database.bat, a `cmd` window opens up and the command is showing on the screen and is executed. However the command is slightly different that what is writing in the batch file. I am getting a rouge space plus a 0 (Zero) appearing in the statement just before the `<` eg

```
C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Server Scripts>restore_database.bat

C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Server Scripts>C:\wamp\mysql\bin\mysql --user=root --password=abc123456 mydatabase  0< C:\Temp\mydatabase.sql
```

ie, after mydatabase I am getting an extra space and a 0 being inserted just before the `<`

How can I correct this and why is it appearing.

I am using Win7 64bit Ultimate as my OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. That **0** character appearing before the redirection symbol is  not a bogus (or "rogue") character.

And this behavior doesn't have anything to do with mysql program, this is default behavior for Microsoft Windows.

**0** is the numeric equivalent of the the STDIN handle, just like **1** is the numeric equivalent of STDOUT and **2** is the numeric equivalent of STDERR.

You could change your .bat file to include the 0 character before the redirection symbol, it wouldn't have any effect.

Ref: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx

Comment: It's odd that Windows, however, shows this designator explicitly when echoing the users batch file commands even though the user doesn't use it explicitly. Is this behavior explained anywhere?